# Surjective and non injective function problem

Tags: functions, monotone-functions

Is there an example for a function which is surjective but not injective with this given:
$f\colon \Bbb N\rightarrow \Bbb N \left(\forall m,n\in\Bbb N\right):m\leq n \Rightarrow f(m)\leq f(n)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $$f(x)=\left\lfloor\frac x2\right\rfloor$$

Comment: Hmm I see, but couldn't that also be injective, cause there is for every elenent in our target quantity also one in our origin quantity. And the definition of injective should be for every element in our target quantity is maximum one element in the origin quantity?

Comment: @AjaxEdm: $f(0)=f(1)$

Comment: @Corvus the one you posted seems correct ;) Put it as an answer that i can upvote it and give it the tick

Comment: @AjaxEdm: Both are correct.

Comment: @Corvus why is the second one correct ?

Comment: @AjaxEdm: It's monotone, surjective and not injective, because, for example, $f(0)=f(1)$.

Comment: @Corvus Wouldn't f(0) be 0 and f(1) be 1/2?

Comment: @AjaxEdm: $\left \lfloor \frac 12\right\rfloor=0$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Comment: @Corvus Ahh I see cause we only have natural numbers right?

Answer (score 2):

$f(0)=0$, $f(n)=n-1$ for $n\ge 1$.